# How can I prerender MathJax - convert Mathjax to HTML on the server side?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mathjax

Given HTML with Mathjax, how can I prerender it, that is, convert it on the server side? My ideal workflow is:

1. START: HTML with embedded MathJax (e.g. `for all $x \i X$`); it displays properly on browsers with MathJax Javascript
2. Run *something*
3. END: HTML with prerendered MathJax; it displays properly on any browser, even without Javascript

This should be doable e.g. via NodeJS, since anything that can be done at the browser should be doable statically / prerendering.

Note that the MathJax is already configured properly in the HTML/JS: I want to use the same config, just prerender it.

Comment: Relevant docs passages: [Server-Side MathJax](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v3.2-latest/upgrading/whats-new-3.0.html#server-side-mathjax). See also MathJax's node repo: https://github.com/mathjax/mathjax-node

Comment: @Brian That link says that support for this has been expanded, but doesn't doc how to do it.